# How do I execute piped output?

Tags: unix

How do I execute an output piped from a bash script?

I got this bash script and I want to execute only the first line of it.

Example: `cat bash_script | head -n 1 | <execute>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... You execute it in bash.

```
cat bash_script | head -n 1 | bash
```